# How can I extract a string sperated by at most one space from an array of chars? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, char

I have an array of characters that I pass to this function that I read in from a file. They look like this:

```
7270706PRRío Cañas Abajo                                   1185    0.238885 18.037675 -66.46701029126  2.6966
```

I want to extract the chars signifying the name of a place from the 9th position of this char array up until the stream of spaces (so in this case "Canas Abajo"). To do this, I tried, calling with a = 9 and stop = 40:

```
   string getPlaceName(const char (&in) [110], int a, int stop){ 
   char ext[48];
   int p =0; int sig = 0;
   string toret;
   for(a, p; a < stop; a+=1, p+=1)
       ext[p] = in[a];
   char * v = strtok(ext, " ");

   while (v) {
    if(sig == 0)
        {string q = (v); toret = q; sig= 1;}
    else
        {string l = (v); toret = toret +" " +l;}  
    v = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
   cout<<"|"<<toret<<"|"<<endl;
   return toret;
}
```

This works for files where the last letter of the string I'm trying to extract is at the end of the line, yet in the example string given, it is returning a jumble of random characters after the name and implies there is no proper null termination. This happens with and without the string q = (v) and string l = (v). What is wrong with my attempt at combining the string and returning?

Comment: Tokenize the string, use strtok(). You can also use std::string::find() method.

Answer (score 0):

Tokenize the string, use strtok(). You can also use std::string::find() method. You can also use std::copy() algorithm. stream iterators are used to copy the stream to the vector as whitespace separated strings.

Use string::substr() to extract a substring from - to position.

```
char myString[] = "7270706PRRío Cañas Abajo                                   1185    0.238885 18.037675 -66.46701029126  2.6966";
char *p = strtok(myString, " ");
while (p) {
    printf ("Token: %s\n", p);
    p = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
```

OR

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string str = "7270706PRRío Cañas Abajo                                   1185    0.238885 18.037675 -66.46701029126  2.6966";

  std::stringstream strstr(str);

  std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(strstr);
  std::istream_iterator<std::string> end;
  std::vector<std::string> results(it, end);

  std::ostream_iterator<std::string> oit(std::cout);
  std::copy(results.begin(), results.end(), oit);
}
```

Comment: I tried to make a string to add the  char * p once it was tokenized so I could return "Canas Abajo" as one string, and it seems to cout properly within the function, yet when I return this string I seem to get more ascii madness. Would you know why?

Comment: Fix getPlaceName() first, that function impl. is unnecessarily over complicated. All you need to do is, read the line, tokenize it (refer various methods in my answer), find out the "name" & return it.

Comment: I've updated my code in the example. Is my method of returning the "name" improper?

Comment: I don't understand the logic, but I would like to suggest you pass toret by reference, don't return the string value. see if anything changes.

Comment: If anything the variation in ascii chars beyond 200 increased about 5%, still getting broken strings.

Comment: One thing I have not understood here is, why are you passing a, stop, Do you really need it, think about it. It is simple, accept the line by reference, tokenize it, return name. The entire logic is complicated.

Comment: Can you please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example that shows your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a method for this before:

```
std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string& text, const char separator)
{
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;

    while ((end = text.find(separator, start)) != std::string::npos) 
    {
        tokens.push_back(text.substr(start, end - start));

        start = end + 1;
    }

    tokens.push_back(text.substr(start));

    return tokens;
}
```

Use this to get a list of tokens and then select the 1st and 2nd index.